# Property "RegistrationForm.firstname" is not defined.

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I'm using the yii-user extension version 0.3, while trying to customize my registration form, i get this error

```
Property "RegistrationForm.firstname" is not defined.
```

below is my code. any idea why?

```
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'email', array('class' => 'input-block-level', 'placeholder' => 'Email')); ?>

    <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password', array('class' => 'input-block-level', 'placeholder' => 'Password')); ?>

    <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'verifyPassword', array('class' => 'input-block-level', 'placeholder' => 'Retype Password')); ?>   

    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'firstname', array('class' => 'input-block-level', 'placeholder' => 'First Name')); ?>

    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'lastname', array('class' => 'input-block-level', 'placeholder' => 'Last Name')); ?>
```

also how would i use the yii language to populate this? so i don't have to hard code it?

```
'placeholder' => 'E-mail'
```

basically `email` would be output as `E-mail`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see, the $model you've used in your code is an object of "RegistrationForm" Model and the error says that there is no property firstname defined in your RegistrationForm Model.

See if you have spelled it correctly.

To use the the attribute label as Placeholder, I think you need to Extend the [CInputWidget](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CInputWidget)

and customize it according to your requirements.

[Reference](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/27748-creating-a-custom-input-widget-with-cinputwidget/)